# Open tabs slowly with jQuery & only allow one tab section to have a tab open at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My developers are having a lot of trouble creating a certain tabular system for my website. My website has several sections of tabs on the same page (for products, so there are tons of them).

[Here is the testing page I put up.](http://leansd.com/)

We need the following to happen:

1. All tabs closed by default
2. I need the tabs to open slowly and close slowly, but only on the first tab open of a tab section. So if I open a tab for the first time on a section it should open slowly. If I click a tab in the same section it should simply replace the tab instead of closing the previous one and opening the next.
3. Notice there are three tab sections. I want it so only one tab section at a time can have a tab open. So if I have a tab open on the first tab section and I click a tab on the second tab section then the currently open one slowly closes at the same time that new section slowly opens. I would like the action to happen at the same time so there is less wait.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9L4y5zf9/1/)

here's what the HTML looks like for each tab:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>content 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>content 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>content 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery is calling a jQuery UI function:

```
  $(function() {
    $( ".tabs" ).tabs({
      collapsible: true
    });
  });
```

Comment: to make them hidden by default, add style="display:none" to the tab content divs (#tabs-1 etc in your example), or otherwise `$.hide()` them. As for opening slowly, not sure what you're looking for there--fade in, slide in etc. As for hiding other tab panes, that's a matter of storing references to the other tab panes, and calling a $.hide() on the their content divs on tab click.

Comment: Here's the [docs for effects on showing tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-show)

Comment: will have a far better chance of getting help if put demo in a code sandbox that can be forked. jsfiddle.net, plnkr.co, codepen.io etc

Comment: @Ted I added the show slow for the tabs but the problem still is having only the first one open only and any tabs next to it just use the panel that has already been opened, instead of closing previous and open current.

Comment: To make them closed by default use `active : false` property. `$( ".tabs" ).tabs({collapsible: true, active : false});`

Comment: Oh I missed that in the API albciff, Good catch! And I have to agree with charlietfl.

Comment: @Ted :) I'm also agree with charlietfl

Comment: @albciff great thank you, applied that. Any recommendation on how I can efficiently close an open tab section if I open a tab in another, BUT prevent tabs in a same section from closing if I open one in the same section?

Comment: will have to bind event handlers to tabs either through API events or standard event approach and have some logic that tells other components to close. Part of reason a decent forkable demo would help

Comment: @charlietfl I can't get one working with all this jQuery code required.

Comment: why? the first 2 I mentioned have one click setups for all the cdn resources you need

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know how to build the fiddle so it works. Here's what I did: http://jsfiddle.net/9L4y5zf9/1/

Comment: you select resources from top left, no need to add anything other than html and initialize plugin http://jsfiddle.net/fb0z3ezd/

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl just found that. Please see the http://jsfiddle.net/9L4y5zf9/1/

Comment: but even simpler the way I set it up, CSS block is empty and only had to check a checkbox and a dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses the `activate` callback and assumes that the other tab collections will be siblings of the activated tab collection

```
  $(function () {
      $(".tabs").tabs({
          collapsible: true,
          show: {
              effect: "blind",
              duration: 800
          },
          active: false,
          activate:function(evt,ui){
              var $currTabs = ui.newTab.closest('.tabs');              
              $currTabs.siblings().tabs("option", { active: false } );             
          }
      });
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fb0z3ezd/1/)**</kbd>

This callback doesn't fire until after the effect seems to have completed so the timing may not be what you want for the closing of the other tabs but it is start.

**Updated**: uses `beforeActivate` callback to collapse other tabs and only animates content opening when all  tabs in collection were previously closed

```
var inactiveOpts = {
    active: false,
    show: {
        effect: 'blind'
    }
}

var $tabs = $(".tabs").each(function () {
    var currTab = this,
        tabsOpts = {
            collapsible: true,
            beforeActivate: function (evt, ui) {
                $tabs.not(this).tabs("option", inactiveOpts)
            },
            activate: function (evt, ui) {
                $(currTab).tabs('option', {
                    show: false
                });
            }
        }
    $.extend(tabsOpts, inactiveOpts);
    $(this).tabs(tabsOpts);

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/fb0z3ezd/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: The problem with this is that one has to open all the way and then the other one closes, which causes a bad jolt on the page. While one opens slowly I need the open one to close slowly. Additionally, in one tab section I only want the open slowly to happen on the first tab open. If I click another tab in the same section no animation should happen until I close it by clicking again.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't. You removed the animation. When a tab on a new section is opened both should animate at the same. One is animating closed, the other is animating open.

Comment: dude, you don't seem to be terribly appreciative and your expectations haven't been absolute either. Feel free to make adjustments. WE ARE HERE TRYING TO HELP, Not working for you

Comment: Of course I'm appreciative, sorry if it doesn't sound like it. I can't figure this out is the problem! Can we chat? I'll even pay you to accomplish this for me.

Comment: I don't see any tabs on that page...are you sure you are using the correct widget?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67502/discussion-between-michael-rader-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another more elegant solution however here there is a solution using `click` event on tab section which closes the others tabs using `activate`:

```
$(function() {
    // get all tabs
    var tabs = $(".tabs").tabs({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false
    });    
    // for each tabs
    $.each(tabs, function(index, element) {
        // if click on div tab
        $(element).click(function(){ 
            // close others except this
            for(var i = 0;i<tabs.length;i++){
                if(i != index){
                    $(tabs[i]).tabs('option','active',false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albciff/6ek0equw/)

*EDIT*:

To change `show` and `hide` animation duration depending in if it's the first open tab or the last closed tab, you can change `show` and `hide` properties on `beforeActivate` event, checking if there is an `ui.oldTab` or and `ui.newTab` (see the [documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate)): . An approach to that could be:

```
$(function() {
    var tabs = $(".tabs").tabs({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
                if(!ui.newTab.length){
                    // collapsing last one set hide "slow"
                    $(this).tabs('option','hide',{ duration : 1000});
                }else{
                    // not collapsing last one set hide "quick"
                       $(this).tabs('option','hide',{ duration : 1});
                }

                if(!ui.oldTab.length){
                       // open first one, show "slow"
                    $(this).tabs('option','show',{ duration : 1000});
                }else{
                    // not first, open "quick"
                    $(this).tabs('option','show',{ duration : 1});
                }

            }
    });    
    // for each tabs
    $.each(tabs, function(index, element) {
        // if click on div tab
        $(element).click(function(){ 
            // close others except this
            for(var i = 0;i<tabs.length;i++){
                if(i != index){
                    // close all
                    $(tabs[i]).tabs('option','active',false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Try the complete [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albciff/6ek0equw/1/)

Comment: This is close but there is no animation. I need animation on the first open of a tab in a section. If another tab of the same section is clicked there is no animation (unless the tab is closed on the second click).

Comment: To add animation play with `show` and `hide` options for `tabs` I give you a possible start point to do so `:)`.

Comment: No there much more to just simply animating it. I need check if a tab in a section has already been opened. If there is a tab already opened then animation will not apply to the other next to it, only on a new section. That is the big problem I am having.

Comment: I make some changes to achieve your goal, check it out `:)`.

Comment: No this is worse, sorry. The tab should animate closed while one animates open.

Comment: @MichaelRader this is what this jsfiddle do: http://jsfiddle.net/albciff/6ek0equw/1/ no? First open tab on each section is animated, when all tabs in the section are collapsed the last one is also animated, when you click a tab on another section this new one is animated and the other from the  previous section is also... if there is an already open tab on the section there is no animation between them. This is what you want or I understand bad your requirements...

Comment: I'm sorry thank you for trying. You are animating the content, not the tabs.